# Broadleaf Commerce Embedded Solr cannot run with root user

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, broadleaf-commerce

I download a fresh 6.1 broadleaf-commerce and run my local machine via `java -javaagent:./admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar -jar admin/target/admin.jar` successfully on mine **macbook**. But in my **centos 7** I run `sudo java -javaagent:./admin/target/agents/spring-instrument.jar -jar admin/target/admin.jar`     with following error

```
2020-10-12 13:20:10.838  INFO 2481 --- [           main] c.b.solr.autoconfigure.SolrServer        : Syncing solr config file: jar:file:/home/mynewuser/seafood-broadleaf/admin/target/admin.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/broadleaf-boot-starter-solr-2.2.1-GA.jar!/solr/standalone/solrhome/configsets/fulfillment_order/conf/solrconfig.xml to: /tmp/solr-7.7.2/solr-7.7.2/server/solr/configsets/fulfillment_order/conf/solrconfig.xml
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 62383.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.
         Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'
2020-10-12 13:20:11.021 ERROR 2481 --- [           main] c.b.solr.autoconfigure.SolrServer        : Problem starting Solr
```

Here is the source code of solr configuration, I believe it is the place to change the configuration to run with the argument `-force` in programming way.

```
package com.community.core.config;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.SearchService;
import org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration;
import org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrSearchServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @author Phillip Verheyden (phillipuniverse)
 */
@Component
public class ApplicationSolrConfiguration {

    @Value("${solr.url.primary}")
    protected String primaryCatalogSolrUrl;
    
    @Value("${solr.url.reindex}")
    protected String reindexCatalogSolrUrl;
    
    @Value("${solr.url.admin}")
    protected String adminCatalogSolrUrl;

    @Bean
    public SolrClient primaryCatalogSolrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(primaryCatalogSolrUrl).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SolrClient reindexCatalogSolrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(reindexCatalogSolrUrl).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SolrClient adminCatalogSolrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(adminCatalogSolrUrl).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrConfiguration blCatalogSolrConfiguration() throws IllegalStateException {
        return new SolrConfiguration(primaryCatalogSolrClient(), reindexCatalogSolrClient(), adminCatalogSolrClient());
    }

    @Bean
    protected SearchService blSearchService() {
        return new SolrSearchServiceImpl();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You posted the full warning, but is there not anything that comes after the error message? If there is, could youp post that? Also, did you try doing what the warning message suggested with `SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS`?

Comment: @phillipuniverse  just want to start it by sudo or root user, therefore, I want to add **-f** to suppress the warning as below: WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.
         Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying you would be better off simply not starting the application as `root`. If you are in Docker, you can use the `USER` command to switch to a non-root user.

The Solr server startup in Broadleaf Community is done programmatically via the `broadleaf-boot-starter-solr` dependency. This is the wrapper around Solr that ties it to the Spring lifecycle. All of the real magic happens in the `com.broadleafcommerce.solr.autoconfigure.SolrServer` class.

In that class, you will see a `startSolr()` method. This method is what adds startup arguments to Solr.

In your case, you will need to mostly copy this method wholesale and use `cmdLine.addArgument(...)` to add additional arguments. Example:

```
class ForceStartupSolrServer extends SolrServer {

    public ForceStartupSolrServer(SolrProperties props) {
        super(props);
    }

    protected void startSolr() {
        if (!isRunning()) {
            if (!downloadSolrIfApplicable()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not download or expand Solr, see previous logs for more information");
            }
            stopSolr();
            synchConfig();
            {
                CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine(getSolrCommand());
                cmdLine.addArgument("start");
                cmdLine.addArgument("-p");
                cmdLine.addArgument(Integer.toString(props.getPort()));

                // START MODIFICATION
                cmdLine.addArgument("-force");
                // END MODIFICATION

                Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
                PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(System.out);
                streamHandler.setStopTimeout(1000);
                executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
                try {
                    executor.execute(cmdLine);
                    created = true;
                    checkCoreStatus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.error("Problem starting Solr", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create an `@Configuration` class to override the `blAutoSolrServer` bean created by `SolrAutoConfiguration` (note the [specific package requirement for `org.broadleafoverrides.config`](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/5.2/broadleaf-concepts/customizing-broadleaf-beans#java-configuration)):

```
package org.broadleafoverrides.config;

public class OverrideConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public ForceStartupSolrServer blAutoSolrServer(SolrProperties props) {
        return new ForceStartupSolrServer(props);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using community version 6.1, but cannot import  com.broadleafcommerce.solr.autoconfigure.SolrServer, the only thing I can import is import  com.broadleafcommerce.autoconfigure.*;

Comment: or should I downgrade to 5.2?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean that you cannot import `SolrServer` directly. Perhaps you are in the `core` project? I tested this class in the `site` project and it overwrote the default `SolrServer` bean without issue https://gist.github.com/phillipuniverse/34479110028d7ce1ee5283eea1bd5cdd